# How to handle the begin/end of the incoming/outgoing call

Tags: android

How do I handle the begin/end of the incoming/outgoing call?

In the other words "to catch the moment when an incoming/outgoing call is beginning/ending" (**the time between** the answer and hang up) and write it in the log.

Android version is 2.3

Comment: [TelephonyManager?](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean by 'handle'? Intent?

OK - here is how:

Add to your manifest XML next lines:

```
<receiver android:name=".Outgoing"> 
                        <intent-filter> 
                            <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL"/>
                        </intent-filter> 
        </receiver>

        <receiver android:name=".Incoming"> 
                        <intent-filter> 
                            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"/>
                        </intent-filter> 
        </receiver>
```

So, as you can see you'll have 2 BroadcastReceiver classes : Outgoing and Incoming.

Here's Outgoing.java:

```
public class Outgoing extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        context.startService(new Intent(context, LogService.class));
}
```

}

(i'm starting my service from this class so that's why i'm using context.startService...)

Here's Incoming.java:

```
public class Incoming extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

        if(null == bundle)
                return;

        String state = bundle.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);

        if(state.equalsIgnoreCase(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING))
        {
            context.startService(new Intent(context, LogService.class));
        }
}


}
```

I'm using this on gingerbread and froyo and it works normally.

Comment: I mean "To catch the moment when an incoming/outgoing call is beginning/ending".

Comment: Does your code really catch  the moment of the start/end  of the calls? I mean **the time** between the answer and hang up.

Comment: Yes, of course, i'm using it, as I said, and i'm able to catch every single call - missed, outgoing and incoming.

Comment: I'm not sure if it cathces the start or the end, but it's more likely that it catches the start of the call.